# how to save listview items/adapter in fragment and restore from back stack

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, fragment, fragment-backstack

I've been tried to search about this problem but I couldn't get any solution.
I've got a problem about saving ListView items in fragment. The case is I have several fragments

> let say FRAGMENT A, FRAGMENT B and FRAGMENT C, and FRAGMENT A has a
>   listview, the item of the listview can be changed when user scroll
>   (just like timeline in social media apps). When I change the fragment
>   A, I used addToBackStack(null) method.

The problem is, how to save the listview and restore its if back button is pressed?

> onSaveInstanceState() is never called because the Activity host is never killed, only change the fragment using this:

```
public void changeFragment(Fragment fragment, ColorDrawable colorDrawable){
    Fragment newFrag = fragment;
    ColorDrawable newColor = colorDrawable;

    String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate (backStateName, 0);
    if (!fragmentPopped){ //fragment not in back stack, create it.
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_fragment, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        ft.commit();
    }

    //to change the actionbar color
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(newColor);
}
```

here is my code trying to save and restore the listview:

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        //try to save listview scroll
        index = myList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View v = myList.getChildAt(0);
        top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - myList.getPaddingTop());
        index = 1;
        //try to save listview items
        savedAdapter = adapter;
        fromBackStack = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        myList.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
        myList.setAdapter(savedAdapter);
    }
```

here the code I've done so far :

```
    package com.ngapainya.ngapainya.fragment;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.ngapainya.ngapainya.R;
import com.ngapainya.ngapainya.activity.volunteer.ContainerActivity;
import com.ngapainya.ngapainya.adapter.HomeAdapter;
import com.ngapainya.ngapainya.fragment.child.DetailPostFragment;
import com.ngapainya.ngapainya.model.Home;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{
    private FragmentActivity myContext;
    private View myFragmentView;
    private ArrayList<Home> filelist;
    private ListView myList;
    private HomeAdapter adapter;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    //try save instance listview
    boolean fromBackStack = false;
    int index;
    int top;
    HomeAdapter savedAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        //try to save listview scroll
        index = myList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View v = myList.getChildAt(0);
        top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - myList.getPaddingTop());
        index = 1;
        //try to save listview items
        savedAdapter = adapter;
        fromBackStack = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        myList.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
        myList.setAdapter(savedAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        myContext = (FragmentActivity) activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        filelist = new ArrayList<Home>();

        //dummy data
        filelist.add(new Home("post", 1)); //post image
        filelist.add(new Home("post", 2)); //post location
        filelist.add(new Home("post", 3)); //post url
        filelist.add(new Home("post", 4)); //become friend with
        filelist.add(new Home("post", 0)); //post status

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        /**
         * Showing Swipe Refresh animation on activity create
         * As animation won't start on onCreate, post runnable is used
         */
        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                                        //do something
                                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                                    }
                                }
        );

        myList = (ListView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.list_home);
        //myList.setAdapter(new HomeAdapter(myContext, filelist));
        adapter = new HomeAdapter(myContext, filelist);
        myList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        if(!fromBackStack) {
            new RemoteDataTask().execute();
        }

        return myFragmentView;
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when swipe refresh is pulled down
     */
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        //do something
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
        ArrayList<Home> new_filelist = new ArrayList<>();
        new_filelist.add(new Home("Post", 4));

        filelist.addAll(0, new_filelist);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Home tmp = (Home) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        DetailPostFragment detailPostFragment = new DetailPostFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        switch (tmp.type) {
            case 0:
                args.putInt("postType", tmp.type);
                detailPostFragment.setArguments(args);
                ((ContainerActivity) getActivity()).changeFragment(detailPostFragment, new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary)));
                break;
            case 1:
                args.putInt("postType", tmp.type);
                detailPostFragment.setArguments(args);
                ((ContainerActivity) getActivity()).changeFragment(detailPostFragment, new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary)));
                break;
            case 2:
                args.putInt("postType", tmp.type);
                detailPostFragment.setArguments(args);
                ((ContainerActivity) getActivity()).changeFragment(detailPostFragment, new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary)));
                break;
            case 3:
                args.putInt("postType", tmp.type);
                detailPostFragment.setArguments(args);
                ((ContainerActivity) getActivity()).changeFragment(detailPostFragment, new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary)));
                break;
            case 4:
                args.putInt("postType", tmp.type);
                detailPostFragment.setArguments(args);
                ((ContainerActivity) getActivity()).changeFragment(detailPostFragment, new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary)));
                break;
        }
    }

    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Home>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Home> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                ArrayList<Home> new_filelist = new ArrayList<Home>();
                new_filelist.add(new Home("post", 3)); //post url
                new_filelist.add(new Home("post", 4)); //become friend with
                new_filelist.add(new Home("post", 0)); //post status
                filelist.addAll(new_filelist);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return filelist;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Home> organization) {
            myList.setAdapter(new HomeAdapter(myContext, filelist));
            // Create an OnScrollListener
            myList.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                                                 int scrollState) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int threshold = 1;
                    int count = myList.getCount();

                    if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        if (myList.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count
                                - threshold) {
                            // Execute LoadMoreDataTask AsyncTask
                            new LoadMoreDataTask().execute();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                     int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });
        }
    }

    public class LoadMoreDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Home>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Home> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                // web service request
                ArrayList<Home> new_filelist = new ArrayList<Home>();
                new_filelist.add(new Home("post", 0)); //post status
                if(new_filelist  != null && new_filelist.size() > 0 ){
                    filelist.addAll(new_filelist);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return filelist;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Home> organization) {
            int position = myList.getLastVisiblePosition();
            adapter = new HomeAdapter(myContext, filelist);
            myList.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            myList.setSelectionFromTop(position, 0);
        }
    }

}
```

I hope someone could help me out, thank you .

> Updated Code
>   This is my code so far, it works when I try to saved the listview items and its adapter, perhaps this is a bit tricky. If someone has any idea would be appreciated.

```
package com.ngapainya.ngapainya.fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.ngapainya.ngapainya.R;
import com.ngapainya.ngapainya.activity.volunteer.ContainerActivity;
import com.ngapainya.ngapainya.adapter.HomeAdapter;
import com.ngapainya.ngapainya.fragment.child.DetailPostFragment;
import com.ngapainya.ngapainya.model.Home;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{
    private FragmentActivity myContext;
    private View myFragmentView;
    private ArrayList<Home> filelist;
    private ListView myList;
    private HomeAdapter adapter;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    /*
    * these variables used to restore the listview
    * when calling the fragment from backstack
    * */
    private boolean fromBackStack = false;
    private HomeAdapter savedAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Home> savedFilelist;

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        savedAdapter = adapter;
        savedFilelist = filelist;
        fromBackStack = true;
        Log.e("onDestroyView", "onDestroyView");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        myContext = (FragmentActivity) activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        Log.e("onCreateView", "onCreateView");

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        /**
         * Showing Swipe Refresh animation on activity create
         * As animation won't start on onCreate, post runnable is used
         */
        /*swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                                        //do something
                                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                                    }
                                }
        );*/

        myList = (ListView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.list_home);
        //myList.setAdapter(new HomeAdapter(myContext, filelist));

        myList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        filelist = new ArrayList<Home>();
        adapter = new HomeAdapter(myContext, filelist);

        if(fromBackStack) {
            filelist = savedFilelist;
            adapter = savedAdapter;
        }

        new RemoteDataTask().execute();
        return myFragmentView;
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when swipe refresh is pulled down
     */
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        ArrayList<Home> new_filelist = new ArrayList<>();
        new_filelist.add(new Home("Post", 4));

        filelist.addAll(0, new_filelist);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        Log.e("onRefresh", "onRefresh");
    }

    /*
    * This method is called whenever the listview item is clicked
    * */

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Home tmp = (Home) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        DetailPostFragment detailPostFragment = new DetailPostFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        switch (tmp.type) {
            case 0:
                args.putInt("postType", tmp.type);
                detailPostFragment.setArguments(args);
                ((ContainerActivity) getActivity()).changeFragment(detailPostFragment, new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary)));
                break;
            case 1:
                args.putInt("postType", tmp.type);
                detailPostFragment.setArguments(args);
                ((ContainerActivity) getActivity()).changeFragment(detailPostFragment, new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary)));
                break;
            case 2:
                args.putInt("postType", tmp.type);
                detailPostFragment.setArguments(args);
                ((ContainerActivity) getActivity()).changeFragment(detailPostFragment, new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary)));
                break;
            case 3:
                args.putInt("postType", tmp.type);
                detailPostFragment.setArguments(args);
                ((ContainerActivity) getActivity()).changeFragment(detailPostFragment, new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary)));
                break;
            case 4:
                args.putInt("postType", tmp.type);
                detailPostFragment.setArguments(args);
                ((ContainerActivity) getActivity()).changeFragment(detailPostFragment, new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary)));
                break;
        }
    }

    /*
    * This method is called in onCreateView method
    * Used to load data from server and populate them into
    * the listview
    * */

    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Home>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Home> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                ArrayList<Home> new_filelist = new ArrayList<Home>();
                //dummy data
                new_filelist.add(new Home("post", 1)); //post image
                new_filelist.add(new Home("post", 2)); //post location
                new_filelist.add(new Home("post", 3)); //post url
                new_filelist.add(new Home("post", 4)); //become friend with
                new_filelist.add(new Home("post", 0)); //post status
                new_filelist.add(new Home("post", 3)); //post url
                new_filelist.add(new Home("post", 4)); //become friend with
                new_filelist.add(new Home("post", 0)); //post status
                filelist.addAll(new_filelist);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return filelist;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Home> organization) {
            myList.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Create an OnScrollListener
            myList.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                                                 int scrollState) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int threshold = 1;
                    int count = myList.getCount();

                    if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        if (myList.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count
                                - threshold) {
                            // Execute LoadMoreDataTask AsyncTask
                            new LoadMoreDataTask().execute();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                     int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });
        }
    }

    /*
    * This method is called when the listview pulled down
    * it will trigger this method to load more items from server
    * */

    public class LoadMoreDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Home>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Home> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                // web service request
                ArrayList<Home> new_filelist = new ArrayList<Home>();
                new_filelist.add(new Home("post", 0)); //post status
                new_filelist.add(new Home("post", 1));
                if(new_filelist  != null && new_filelist.size() > 0 ){
                    filelist.addAll(new_filelist);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return filelist;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Home> organization) {
            int position = myList.getLastVisiblePosition();
            //adapter = new HomeAdapter(myContext, filelist);
            myList.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            myList.setSelectionFromTop(position, 0);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out...
I don't know whether this is the best solution or not but it works so far for me.
I only need one method and several variables, like this.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    savedAdapter = adapter;
    savedFilelist = filelist;
    fromBackStack = true;
    Log.e("onDestroyView", "onDestroyView");
}
```

Thanks SO.

Comment: You must save state (if needed) in onSaveInstanceState() and not in onDestroy(). Regarding your adapter, you need to initialize it in onCreate() instead, optionally filling it with the previously saved state. It will be preserved when the view is destroyed and re created. The scroll position will be restored automatically as soon as you set the initialized adapter on the ListView.

Comment: @BladeCoder The problem is, my fragment is not destroyed but detach so that's why onSaveInstanceState() is never called. If I can use onSaveInstanceState() instead of onDestroy() method perhaps it'd be the best solution. Do you have any idea sir how to make onSaveInstanceState called in this case?

Comment: You don't need it to be called if your fragment's View is just destroyed an re-created. All your instance variables will still be initialized when the view is re-created, so you can just re-attach your existing adapter that you initialized in onCreate().

Comment: @BladeCoder check my updated question and code please. Thank you so much for your response sir